# What is the best way to lock object by private mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, mutex

I need to lock object by private mutex in some external functions. What is the best way to do this?
I want something like this

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

class Test
{
public:
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lockGuard()
        {
            return std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(mutex);
        }

private:
    std::mutex mutex;
};

int main()
{
    Test test;
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock = test.lockGuard();
    //...
}
```

But `lock_guard` copy contructor is deleted. How can I do something like this?

Comment: use `unique_lock` instead?

Comment: Will I get what I need if I replace `lock_guard` by `lock_guard`?

Comment: If the object is locked only from the outside, and not from the inside, why does the mutex need to be declared inside it at all?

Answer (score 2):

Just use `std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` instead.  It is *not* copyable, but it *is* movable, allowing the pattern you show.

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

class Test
{
public:
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lockGuard()
        {
            return std::unique_lock<std::mutex>(mutex);
        }

private:
    std::mutex mutex;
};

int main()
{
    Test test;
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock = test.lockGuard();
    //...
}
```

`std::unique_lock<std::mutex>` has a broadened API relative to `std::lock_guard` including:

- Move constructible.
- Move assignable.
- Swappable.
- lock()
- unlock()
- try_lock()
- try_lock_for()
- try_lock_until()
- release()
- owns_lock()

In other words, since you can unlock and move from a `unique_lock`, it is not guaranteed to hold the lock on the mutex (you can check that it does with `owns_lock()`).  In contrast an invariant of `lock_guard` is that it always holds the lock on the mutex.

Answer (score 1):

The `std::unique_lock<T>` has a move constructor defined and can be used as you like, but the approach is not very successful itself.
You should review your locking granularity, usually if you can't provide internal synchronization and ask user to maintain lock while performing operations (or when you need to perform multiple operations) on an object, there is no reason to store the mutex inside the object.

If I had to store the mutex inside object, I would use some wrapper which allows me to do the following:

```
locking_wrapper<Test> test;
test.do_locked([] (Test & instance) {
    /* The following code is guaranteed not to interleave with
     * any operations performed on instance from other threads. */
    // your code using instance here
});
```

The `locking_wrapper<T>` would store store an instance of an object inside and provide a reference to it while maintaining a lock on internal mutex. Relying on the compiler's ability to inline code, such approach should give no overhead above what you're trying to do in your question.

The general idea on implementing the `locking_wrapper` is as follows:

```
template<typename T>
class locking_wrapper
{
    mutable std::mutex mutex;
    // the object which requires external synchronization on access
    T instance;

public:
    /* Here we define whatever constructors required to construct the
     * locking_wrapper (e.g. value-initialize the instance, take an 
     * instance passed by user or something different) */
    locking_wrapper() = default;
    locking_wrapper(const T & instance) : instance{instance} {}

    // Takes a functor to be performed on instance while maintaining lock
    template<typename Functor>
    void do_locked(Functor && f) const {
        const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{mutex};
        f(instance);
    }
};
```

You may pass whatever callable-entity to `do_locked` as you see fit, however calling it with a lambda-expression as I've suggested previously will give it the best chances to be inlined without any overhead.

Please note that using this approach with references, movable objects or some other kind I have not yet foreseen would require some modifications to the code.

Comment: `self` is an object of type `Test` stored inside `test`. Maybe the name is misleading, I should have called it `instance` or `object`.

Comment: Any particular reason why your parentheses do not match?
And I will ask some more explanation on that lambda magic there.

Comment: Don't match how, you mean indentation? Feel free to ask.

Comment: I've change the lambda-expression argument from `self` to `instance` for clarity.